# How come Lauren isn't harmed during her relationship with Bo?

Tags: lost-girl

In the TV show 'Lost Girl', Bo is a succubus, and succubi survive by feeding off the sexual energy of others, which can lead to death of the 'food' during the process.

Up until recently, Bo went a period of time without 'feeding' while in a monogamous relationship with Lauren, a human doctor who is aware of what Bo is and aware of the Fae. During which time, Bo started getting weaker - did Lauren not get harmed because Bo wasn't feeding at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time Bo and Lauren actually hook up in the series, Bo has developed a significant amount of control over her powers.  She still doesn't have complete control or know all of what she can do, but she can control how much she feeds and when.  If I recall correctly, Bo rarely, if ever, actually feeds on Lauren.  If she did feed on her, she had enough control over herself to prevent any harm coming to Lauren.

Also, it's implied in the series that as long as she doesn't take all of a person's essence, they heal over time.